# How to replace string given its "starting index" and "string to replace" in an editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am working on string replacement in an `contenteditable` div. When user types `:`, I store its index in some variable.

**Consider example 1:**

```
<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">
    the quick brown fox jumps over a :lazy dog
</div>
```

According to above example, the starting index is 34 and the end index must be the index of near by white space i.e., 39 and the replacing string is *sleeping*.
Given that, the ouput must be *the quick brown fox jumps over a sleeping dog*

**Consider example 2:**

```
<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">
    the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy :dog
</div>
```

According to above example, the starting index is 39 and the end index must be the index of near by white space (but in this case, it must be an *EOL*) and the replacing string is *cat*.
Given that, the output must be *the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy cat*

I tried with below code but user would eventually lose his/her format already done to the part of the document (for ex: **brown** may be bolded, *jumps* may be italicised).

`$('#editableDiv').text($('#editableDiv').text().replace(searchString, replaceString));`

I even tried with `$('#editableDiv').html($('#editableDiv').html().replace(searchString, replaceString));` but `.html()` will return string with html code thus index may vary accordingly.

The question remains is how to replace string without losing its format given, **starting  index** for search and **replace string**.

**Edit**
Function to get Caret Index within a div

```
getCaretPosition : function(){
        var element = document.getElementById("editableDiv");
        var caretOffset = 0;
        f (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
            var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
            var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
            preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
            caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
        }
        return caretOffset;
    }
```

I will call `getCaretPosition` when user types `':'` to capture its index within the div.

Comment: Why do you need the index?

Comment: provide a working fiddle please

Comment: @nouphal. Its because, `replace` function replaces first occurrence of the matching string. For example, if I have a sentence like *this that this that*, and now I would like to replace **second** *that* in the sentence. Fortunately, `replace` will replace **first** *that* instead of second. Thanks.

Comment: @shahe. Oops!. I hope I put up everything to understand the issue. could you please specify what you would like to see in fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "replace string without losing its format" ?

Comment: @shahe. Here is the excerpt from my question. for ex: **brown** may be bolded, *jumps* may be italicised. $('#editableDiv').text($('#editableDiv').text().replace(searchString, replaceString)); would work but eventually loses format already done and the resulting string would simply look like `the quick brown fox jumps over a sleeping dog`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">
    the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy :dog
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace){
    if(!replace) 
        return this;

    return this.replace(new RegExp('[' + search + ']', 'g'), replace);
};


var content = $('#editableDiv').html();
content = content.replaceAll(":dog", "cat");

$('#editableDiv').html(content);
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SL76e/

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work if more than one `:dog` present in the sentence. The function will always replace first occurrence of the matching string. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Metri/9pdc8/1/) Thanks

Comment: Thanks but this seems to be replacing all occurrences of `:dog`. What if I want to modify only one which is at the end of my sentence and not anywhere else. I thank for your patience. This is the very tough issue I am facing. I googled, binged and even asked many of my friends and result is nobody knows. I struck on this for over 3 days. The reason why I am mentioning starting index is to avoid global search for string in a sentence. Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my question and added `getCaretPosition`. This must clear your doubt. Thanks

Comment: and how are you calling the replace function? when the user is typing or when other action is performed?

Comment: What I posted here is the just excerpt of my work. I am working on an autocomplete for div. When user type `:`, a suggestion list pops up for suggestion, and once user makes selection from drown down, the selected text has to replaced from `:` till the first white space. Here is the [screenshot](http://snag.gy/Gowb6.jpg) of my work Thanks

Comment: I see what you mean, anyways I can't think of anything right now to solve the problem, but maybe you can think of another ways to do it, jquery autocomplete ui's are your choices, here: check this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/